# Using WebP image format in Android 2.3

Tags: android, webp

I've googled for some java library that will let me load and display WebP images in Android 2.3 and above. I couldn't find anything. Android 4.0+ comes with built-in support for WebP but I need to support 2.3+. Do you know of any libraries I can use?